# CSOM Retrieving ListItemCollection is empty

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom, azure-api-apps, sharepoint-list

I have tried to make a simple console application that retrieves list items from Share Point Online. It works fine when I retrieve list of the sites or list titles from the site, but I receive no list items when I try to get it from the particular list.
I've listed many examples of similar tasks and almost all of them were written in the same way. That's why I don't exclude that the reason of my case might be in an insufficient permissions (I attach a screenshot of the API permissions).

Please, check my code and permissions. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Application code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace SharePointTrigger
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri site = new Uri("https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MyProject");
            string user = $"ServiceUser@MyCompany.com";
            string rawPassword = $"password";
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in rawPassword) password.AppendChar(c);

            using (var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager()) //HELPER CLASS TO OBTAIN ACCESS TOKEN
            using (var context = authenticationManager.GetContext(site, user, password))
            {

                //RETRIVING LIST TITLE - WORKS FINE
                /*
                Web web = context.Web;
                context.Load(web.Lists,
                lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                                    list => list.Id));

                context.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (SP.List list in web.Lists)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
                }
                */

                //RETRIVING LIST ITEM
                Web myWeb = context.Web;
                SP.List myList = myWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("List_of_Items");

                SP.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = myList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

                context.Load(listItemCollection,
                            eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                                                        item => item,
                                                        item => item["Title"],
                                                        item => item["ID"]
                                                        )
                            );

                context.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (SP.ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + listItem["ID"].ToString() + "Title: " + (string)listItem["Title"].ToString());

                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

API permissions
[API permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VehUr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like permission issue on checking your app permissions or Code issue.

However, looking at the below line :

```
SP.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = myList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
```

You are trying to bring in all the items.

A similar behavior is observed of returning the empty items when the list is a very large list (>5000 or more than 12 lookup columns) or [the list hits a list threshold](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#:%7E:text=SharePoint%20has%20resource%20throttles%20and,lists%2C%20but%20keep%20good%20performance))

If you are falling on the above scenario - you could create a index and filter the items.

You can use CAML query to filter the items instead of trying to fetch all the items in a single go !

Reference for CAML query :
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/filtering-list-item-using-caml-query-in-sharepoint/m-p/1415904

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94631/filtering-list-using-caml-query-and-binding-it-to-dropdown-in-c

Also, I would check whether the items have a item level permission.

**List settings -> Advanced Settings**

[image]

Ideally, you should not encounter this issue because of the above, however this settings increases number of the scopes and may cause to hit the threshold sooner because.

Comment: @Mikhail - wanted to check whether the above helped or do you have any queries?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As for item number limits the list contains only ten items. However I've made a note of your advice for the further code optimization. 
As for the second assumption I've scrolled over "Advanced Section" for several times and it looks like that "Item-level permission" option was removed/replaced from this section or it unavailable for me due the absence of permission. 
Have you faced with the absence of "Item-level permission" option?

Comment: What is the list template ? (Custom List, Tasks List ? )

Comment: Also, do you have multiple look up columns ?

Comment: The list template is "GenericList"("CustomList", ListTemplateId=100) and there are no computed columns.

Comment: Satya V, as for absence option "item-level security" I've found topic with the similar issue with SharePoint 2013 https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191493/modify-the-writesecurity-property-for-an-issue-tracking-list/191500#191500 but this trick doesn't work for SharePoint Online. If I correct it means that I should check the value of the attribute "ReadSecurity" https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sharepoint/dev/schema/readsecurity-element . Have you know the method how to check it?

Comment: I can also take it up offline for a closer look and provide a quick and specialized assistance, please send an email with subject line “Attn:Sathya” to AzCommunity[at]Microsoft[dot]com referencing this thread

Comment: The current value of "ReadSecurity" for all lists is equal to "1" it means that "All users have Read access to all items."
Ok, thanks, I will contact you if I don't find any solution.